# After upgrading PostgreSQL from 8.4 to 9.1 pg gem doesn't connect to the database

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

As the title says, I've upgraded the PostgreSQL database from version 8.4 to 9.1.

My `pg_hba.conf` file contains following:

```
local   all        all            trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I also ran these commands:

```
sudo gem uninstall pg
sudo apt-get remove libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo gem install pg
sudo service postgresql restart
```

When I run `psql` from the command line all works properly, but here's what happens when I try to connect from the Ruby console:

```
$:  /va$ sudo pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'pg'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'mydb' )
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg.rb:40:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Pg gem is using a `libpq` version that defaults to a different `unix_socket_directory` to the one your new server uses. Most likely your new server uses `/tmp` and your old one used `/var/run/postgresql`.

You can force a TCP/IP connection by specifying `localhost` as the target host to connect to, e.g a connstring like `dbname=fred host=localhot user=bob`, or however you're giving the parameters to the Pg gem. That's not really the best answer, though.

Instead, you should either:

- Rebuild the `pg` gem against the updated `libpq` from your new PostgreSQL install. To do that, set `PATH` so that the `pg_config` from the new PostgreSQL install is first on the path before rebuilding the Pg gem. You can check the version with `pg_config --version`.

or

- Specify the `unix_socket_directory` to connect to explicitly, with `host=/tmp dbname=fred user=bob`. The `host` parameter can take a hostname *or* a path to a socket directory. Doing this means you're still using nice efficient unix sockets for your sessions and not paying unnecessary TCP/IP overheads.